# Span issue in CSS

Tags: css

I have two Spans I want span1 to be exactly below span2, even if span1 changes height dynamically.

```
<span id="Div3" style="Z-INDEX: 126; LEFT: 8px; WIDTH: 99.06%; TOP: 5px; visibility: visible;"
                runat="server" ><asp:image id="Image1" 
                style="Z-INDEX: 127; LEFT: 16px; right: 709px;" runat="server"
tabIndex="10"></asp:image></span>
```

The above Span has an image, whose height can change dynamically.

I want this span

```
<span>Exactly below the image</span>
```

to be exactly below the span in which image is placed.

Could anyone help ??

Comment: please include a proper fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created 2 `span`s. One with a `img` in it, and one with `h1` in it.

```
<span class="span1">
    <img src="http://www.online-image-editor.com/styles/2013/images/example_image.png" alt="">
</span>

<span class="span2">
    <h1>I'm span #2!</h1>
</span>
```

Both of the `span`s i have given the `display` property of `block`. This will make them stack under each other.

```
span {
    display: block;
}
```

And gave the `img` some `width`and `height`.

```
.span1 > img {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

**[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/qt625/)**

Answer (score 0):

you forgetting about setting: `position: absolute` and `top:` on both spans. ...if you want to positioning them absolutely.

if you just want them in the document flow then remove top/left/z-index from your styles - they doesn't have any result on the outcome until you add `position:absolute;` or `position:relative;`.